# Add favicon from Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring-mvc, favicon

I'm working in spring mvc application as a new bee. I need to set up a favicon for the application which does not have any common file to do this. So instead of placing the relevant code lines for all the JSP s, I'm thinking of doing this using application-servlet.xml which calls for any HTTP request. Can anyone help me on doing this with one shot ?
You are welcome for suggest any other easy way to do this.

edited-
I was thinking that, executing javascript code code for any request, may be help to this. But not sure that is possible as well as how I can do that

Answer (score 11):

Just to expand on NimChimpsky's anwer... put the favicon in the root (or images) directory and reference it the usual way in your JSP pages (or better still use SiteMesh to specify it once). E.g.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/favicon.ico" />
```

But there is a gotcha when using Tomcat, where the favicon won't get served from inside the webapp due it being a "unknown" mine type. The fix to add a custom mime type entry in web.xml:

```
<!-- Mimetype needed for tomcat to serve favicon images -->
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ico</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I don't want to put that code to all my 136 jsps. I can already success in get it working for single file. But I don't need to repeat.

Comment: You don't need the `<link rel...>` code in every page but it is considered the "standard" way of doing it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon. You DO need to serve it from your server/container ROOT directory in that case, which is problematic when running your servlet with a context path. IMHO the best solution is to use the `<link rel=...>` tag in conjunction with SiteMesh or Tiles, where you only have to set it once in your decorator/template file.

Answer (score 2):

Just store `favicon.ico` in the root of webapp (aka the one up from WEB-INF) directory

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can't do this for all the application severs of my application users. I need to do it from application itself. Thanks anyway

Comment: that doesn't make sense. The location is within the application code ... what exactly do you require ? A favicon without using a favicon.ico ?

Comment: Think this is standalone application. So the favicon.ico should be in my application but not inside server/webapps/ROOT

Comment: That is your application (well where it is deployed to) - I am talking about adding to "yourProject>src>main>webapp" where you probably have directories for images, css (maybe jsps), store the favicon.ico there.  Your applicationConfig.xml is stored in "yourProject>src>main>webapp>WEB-INF".

Comment: I placed the icon (app/web/favicon.ico as well as app/web/images/favicon.ico). When build the app (with ant) it is placed as tomcat/webapps/app/favicon.ico. But I still get the tomcat default icon. I didn't use relevant code (<link ... bla bla>) in my jsps (136 jsps) because that is not my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="frequent"
 class="active tab-pane fade in active text-center">
    <jsp:include page="questionDisplay.jsp" />
    </div>
</div>
```