# Issue in using favicon in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, favicon

I am trying to use favicon in my spring application hosted locally. As per [favicon.ico not displaying in spring mvc 3.2.2 per Tomcat 7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178658/favicon-ico-not-displaying-in-spring-mvc-3-2-2-per-tomcat-7-0) , I have added

```
  <mime-mapping>
<extension>ico</extension>
<mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

in my web.xml:

```
 <display-name>Coaching</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Coaching</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ico</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Adding

```
       <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

in config.xml is giving me error while running the application or application is not running actually. My applicationContext.xml is :

```
              <context:component-scan base-package="com.coaching.controller" />

<!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views 
    directory -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">



    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

My favicon.ico is in the root of webapp (aka the one up from WEB-INF) directory ([Add favicon from Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703678/add-favicon-from-spring-mvc)) . But it is not appearing in web address bar. I am rendering it as

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

In head of the jsp page. I have even tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/17039121/2116229 but the application was not running again.

I have tried several locations of the icon but no result. It must be requiring some spring mvc configuration. Can someone tell me what I am missing.

> I hope favicon appears also in localhost too.

Comment: A comment, not related to your problem, on your configuration. You are loading your configuration twice, basically duplicating all your beans. Both the `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener` load the same xml file (applicationContext.xml).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.. :) Just out of curiosity, would that have impacted my app in long run? Like memory issue or any other effect...

Comment: As you are duplicating your beans you basically duplicating the memory usage of your application. When your configuration grows and gets more complex you can also experience more "fun" issues (at least that is in my experience as one who solves those issues :) ).

Comment: Alright....so even beans are initialized twice, would both of them live throughout application lifecycle? Don't you think One of them should be garbage collected as only one set of beans would be in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping of your dispatcher servlet is the problem. It only reacts to *.html everything else is ignored.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This basically makes your `<mvc:resources */>` and `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` unused. You should map the servlet to / to have everything pass through the DispatcherServlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Next to that you have a mismatch in your servlet element and servlet-mapping. The names should match. So I guess the name should be 'Coaching' instead of 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Coaching</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: That did it...can you please explain me the role of <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> ?

Comment: When mapping the `DispatcherServlet` to / that (kind of) breaks the proper working of the application server. Normally requests that cannot be handled by the application are handled by the servlet container. The `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` fixes that, any request that cannot be handled by the DispatcherServlet will be passed on to the servlet container.