# Favicon missing?

Tags: html, css

I'm loading the favicon using

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../resources/img/favicon.png">
```

This path clearly exists but I dont get any image

all the times.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It doesnt exist

Comment: Use developer tools of your browser or open the URL used in loaded page directly, and check the image's path

Comment: it is looking for an .ico instead of png

Comment: yes it exists. it seems it's trying to load /favicon.ico. I'm not getting any icon in my browser tab

Comment: Ok I fixed the missing .ico but I cant put the favicon in my browser. what am I missing here?

Comment: Hi asdasd, I have added an answer below. I hope this will help you.

Comment: What are you hosting the web page on? Some hosts need you to put the ico file somewhere else in the directory

Comment: I'm loading it on my navbar so it should work on all pages. I dont get any error, it just doesn't load so I think it has something to do with Spring

Comment: Do you have a live link I could look at?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities.

1. Your path is not correct
2. Your code is not working properly

(3. Your image is not correct spelled/does not exist, but I leave this option because that would be a failure, lol)

Try this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../resources/img/favicon.png">
```

If this code above is not working, you need to fix the href path. (maybe move the favicon to the source map and put the favicon code inside the `head` tag inside your `index.php`)

**In case you move the favicon to the source map:**

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
```

Some example code I have found on the internet:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="demo_icon.gif" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hello world!</h2>
<p>Open this page in a <a href="tryhtml5_link_sizes.htm" target="_blank">new window</a> to see the favicon.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> The sizes attribute is not currently supported in any of the major browsers.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Explanation:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_sizes.asp

To be sure your favicon is loaded press CTRL+F5. Not sure if it is needed instead of 'just' F5 (page reload).

Comment: also didnt work. I dont get any error now. it just doesnt load the icon to the browser

Comment: Can you try this? `<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="http://news.cdn.leagueoflegends.com/public/images/misc/Background.jpg">`. And press `CTRL+F5` afterwards

Comment: I'm using Spring if that makes any difference

Comment: Did you CTRL+F5? Ah spring, I dont know. I've found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703678/add-favicon-from-spring-mvc. Does this work?

Comment: Try the link I gave you in previous comment. It should do it. I've never used spring before.